# strange #.[some char] added to the page address in firefox

Tags: asp.net, .net, http, browser

[Asp.net website, .net framework 4]

I noticed a strange thing in my web page address, With every new page requested the address of the page automatically attached with somthing like (#.UTedxFc5stU) at the end of the address after loading completed (maybe cause redirect too), this happend with only .net framework 4 applications, 
and not happend with my other applications using 3.5 !.

- this happend in firefox, chrome only, not with internet explorer.

this an example:

http://egypt.motorsyard.com/cars/used, open it in firefox and you will see somthing like this http://egypt.motorsyard.com/cars/used#.UTehGVc5stU

what is this, and how I stop it ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your webconfig for url rewriting code.

i think this is URL redirecting issue.

**Edit**

If you have characters that look like #.TuomlFaZCSo in the URL those are address bar tracking codes. They provide a way to see how many people visit your site from users copying the URL from the address bar. If you have characters that include the name of a service, like #.TuomlFaZCSo.facebook then those are people returning from a link shared using that service.

To disable them using the client API, do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_config = {
data_track_address_bar: false,
data_track_clickback: false 
};
</script>
```

If you want to disable them using the Wordpress plugin look for their respective checkboxes on the Advanced tab of the AddThis plugin settings page.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that, so I removed all rewriting tags from web.config and test again but the problem not resolved

Comment: Are you pass any querystring in that page?

Comment: Yes, based on your answer I found that the problem came from addthis component, specially when the analytics is enabled, addthis used this extra to collect statistics as you said, but its too bad because it cause redirect or atleast flash the screen !. thank you for help.